# In serialport communication, data is received multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I made a loopback with TX and RX and tested it with one COM3 port.

```cs
serialport.DataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
  var data = serialport.ReadExisting();
  readRichTextBox.AppendText($"{data}\n"); // Cross-Thread Possibility
}
```

With `\n` you can see that the data is received multiple times.

ex) Input hello and hi

```cs
h
e
l
l
o
h
i
```

serialport is the default state.

Expects a result value like this:

```cs
hello
hi
```

Comment: `ReadExisting`  *Reads all immediately available bytes*. So you start sending 'h' and that becomes then available so it add the `h` to the textbox with the linefeed you added there.  But it is also possible that it receives `hel` and then `lo` and then `h` and `i`.  There is nothing in your code that dictates that it should output what you expect. It might once in a while ...

Comment: Either you adapt the communication contract by sending a certain character at the end of a line or the entire transmission, or you need to collect the incoming data until you can match the expected input. It seems you have control over both sides, so I would suggest to attempt the first suggestion

Comment: You need to come up with your application protocol. As is, you will get the system behaviour. And that is "read immediately what is there". So you get exactly what you asked for.

Comment: [SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) states: _Gets or sets the number of bytes in the internal input buffer before a DataReceived event occurs...The number of bytes in the internal input buffer before a DataReceived event is fired. The default is 1._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say use serialPort.ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting().